# pandas dataframe isin() series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Number1': {1: '11', 5: '12', 6: '13', 7: '14', 4: '32'},
                   'Number2': {1: '22', 5: '23', 6: '11', 7: '25', 4: '26'},
                   'Number3': {1: '31', 5: '32', 6: '33', 7: '12', 4: '35'}})
```

[image]

Where I'm trying to check if any value of the dataframe is in a series. If at least one of them is in it, return the row. However, I'm stuck in the "checking" step:

```
s = pd.Series([11,12,15,20,24,40,60,80])
df.isin(s)
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problem here,

1st `df` `dtype` is string but `s` is `int` ,2nd the `isin` with `list` and `Series` are not the same ,`Series` will check the index as well.

```
df.isin(s.astype(str).tolist())
Out[245]: 
   Number1  Number2  Number3
0     True    False    False
1     True    False    False
2    False     True    False
3    False    False     True
4    False    False    False
df.isin(s.astype(str))
Out[246]: 
   Number1  Number2  Number3
0     True    False    False
1     True    False    False
2    False    False    False
3    False    False    False
4    False    False    False
```

Comment: Ups ! I didn't know that thing about the index. I just updated the dataframe (put in a new index), as it can't be a reference to the problem. Is there a way to "desactivate" the index checker of `isin()`?

Comment: @Chris like what i did for the first one, adding tolist()